# HTML table cell width - issue with heading globalization

Tags: html, html-table

I have the following table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="10%">Heading1</td>
        <td width="15%">Heading2</td>
        ....
        <td width="5%">Heading3</td>
    </tr>
    ....
</table>
```

the width of the cell is defined by the width of the first row's cells. So far, so good.

If I translate the headings to other language - the text in the cell changes its length and the result is bad looking table - some cell with a lot of space, while for others there is not enough such to display the text in them.

What should I do?

I have try so many different variations - with width - auto/percent/combination of them and nothing works.

Has anyone have an idea how to set the width in a way to work good with the context dynamically?

I think about some JavaScript function too - I can get the text of each heading before construction the html and according to its length to set the width of the table?

Comment: Centering the text may make it look better. Also maybe just try it without any widths being set.

Comment: remove the width and table  cell will automatically adjust accordingly

Comment: Yes, i have try this, but then the cell have equal width and a column that stores only few digits has length as a column that stores date or address.

Comment: so for your problem you should write a custom function in javascript
to get the content of the column header and  deside the width accordingly to the no of char in it

Comment: Yes, I will try to do something like this tomorrow and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the column is the same for all rows, you can't change this behavior. You can omit the width paramater, table will automatically adjust. You can try to set "min-width" css property if you do not want the columns to be too thin.

Comment: The min-width of a my cells does not cause the issue. If I omit the width parameter I will have cells with equal width and the large context of some of them will be display into several lines. At the other hand table that stores only few digits has length as a column that stores date or address.

Comment: do you have table-layout: fixed ?